# Guidance on choice of ttk layout

Tags: python, tkinter, gridview, layout

Can anyone give me high level guidance (or just a link) on choice of ttk widgets, please? I'm new to tkinter. Issues such as whether to use a frame, and whether to use a ttk Treeview or a tk Listbox for a simple list?

I have something running, but I think all the small problems I have are because I don't see how it should all work together. Win64 now, perhaps my Linux Mint & Ubuntu boxes later.

A colleague has already recommended using ttk widgets where applicable, and tk for the rest. Now he's gone on holiday for 4 weeks :-)

So I have a resizeable window, 2x2 grid layout, with 2 cells for two lists in Treeview widgets used as simple lists (with vertical scrollbars), the 3rd cell for details of one item, and the 4th for everything else.

(Originally, I copied some example code that put everything in a frame that filled the main window. I removed it, because it didn't seem to gain me anything.)

1. Does that grid layout make sense? It doesn't have to be good looking. Just functional.
2. Can I then use another grid layout to organise everything in one cell of the main grid layout?
3. Could I use a pack layout in that one cell, even though the main layout is grid?

Maybe it's my post-covid brain fog, but every line of code is a battle, and it's harder when I'm not sure I'm heading the right way.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Roops

Comment: too many questions. But first you should check in Google for `ttk widgets`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the format. To be clear, web searches for ttk is where I started and the problem is advice and examples that conflict, or use different approaches that don't fit together.